# nicescroll mousescrollstep does not scroll exact pixels?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, scroll, nicescroll

This is from nicescrolls website:

> mousescrollstep - scrolling speed with mouse wheel, default value is
>   40 (pixel)

So when I want to make it 5 scrolls for a user to scroll through a 1080px div I do
1080/5 right, which is 216px.

But when I make

```
 $('body').niceScroll({
    mousescrollstep: 216,
  })
```

It scrolls 400 on google chrome

Example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwevyW?editors=101

Answer (score 0):

The way this plugin is coded. It uses a function webkit browsers do not support.
Use another plugin.

https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll/issues/127

Gib.